# Как добавлять в корзину выбранный товар?

Tags: php, mysql

такая проблема:
Когда я открываю страницу с товарами одной из категорий, то в корзине уже добавились товары(когда корзина пуста, автоматом добавляются товары), а надо чтобы добавлялся нужный товар по клику.
Интернет - магазин я делаю для курсовой работы. В первый раз делаю сайт с PHP и базой данных, поэтому пока не очень понимаю.
Вот код вывода товаров и добавления в корзину:

```
<?php 
session_start();
  ?>
      <?php
      $status="";
      $idcat = $_GET['idcat'];
      $dbUser = 'root';
      $dbName = 'lshop';
      $dbPass = ' ';
      $mysqli = new mysqli('localhost', $dbUser, $dbPass, $dbName);
      $query = "set names utf8";
      $mysqli->query($query);
      $query="SELECT * FROM product WHERE id_category = '$idcat'";
      $results = $mysqli->query($query);
      while($x=$results->fetch_assoc()){

        $tovars[] = array(
          'id' => $x['id'],
          'quantity'=>1,
          'img' => $x['img'],
          'name' => $x['name'],
          'price' => $x['price'],
          );

}

 foreach($tovars as $x){
   echo '
       <div class="tovar">
         <form method="post" action="">
        <a href="tt.php?id='.$x['id'].'"><img src='.$x['img'].'></a>
          <div class="tovar-list">
            <h3>'.$x["name"].'</h3>
            <span class="price">'.$x["price"].'</span>
            <button type="submit" class="buy">Buy now</button>
              <a class="button" href="cart.php?id=$x">В корзину</a>
            </div>
            </form>
          </div>';
  }

?>
<?php
if(!empty($_SESSION["shopping_cart"])) {
$cart_count = count(array_keys($_SESSION["shopping_cart"]));
?>
<div class="cart_div">
<a href="cart.php"><img src="../images/cart-icon.png" /> Корзина<span>
<?php echo $cart_count; ?></span></a>
</div>
<?php
}
?>
<?php
        if(empty($_SESSION["shopping_cart"])) {
    $_SESSION["shopping_cart"] = $tovars;
    $status = "<div class='box'>Product is added to your cart!</div>";
}else{
    $array_keys = array_keys($_SESSION["shopping_cart"]);
    if(in_array($x["id"],$array_keys)) {
  $status = "<div class='box' style='color:white;'>
  Product is already added to your cart!</div>";  
    } else {
    $_SESSION["shopping_cart"] = array_merge(
    $_SESSION["shopping_cart"],
    $tovars
    );
    $status = "<div class='box'>Product is added to your cart!</div>";
  }
  }
  ?>
```

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: Нужно чтобы товар добавлялся по клику

Comment: Товар, который я выбрал, а не все товары